# Generate CSRF Token Asynchronously

Tags: logout, csrf

EE 5.4.0

I'm developing an admin dashboard using ReactJS. I have a class that I'm using as an API to handle actions sent from the frontend. Part of this frontend is a member section that has a logout button.

The logout buttons are using a `csrf_token` as an href in a link that looks like this:

`href="https://www.domain.com/?ACT=15&amp;csrf_token={token}"`

I'm trying to get/generate that csrf_token value in my class and then return it to the frontend so I can have a working logout link in my component.

I can't use the normal EE logout tags because they won't be recognized in React components.

I've also tried using `EE.CSRF_TOKEN`, as suggested [here](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/guidelines/security.html#forms-in-the-control-panel), but I'm getting a notice that says `Use of undefined constant EE - assumed 'EE'`. It does return a value that resembles a csrf token, but when I test that using the ACT structure in the url, I get an error.

Is there a built in way to do this that I'm just missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a currently valid CRSF token to any location you like in your template output using the Single Global Variable [{csrf_token}](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/globals/single-variables.html#csrf_token) - so one solution to your issue is to write this value into a data-* parameter linked to a hidden or otherwise unused div and read the value from there into your React app.

HTH

Comment: That'll do it! Thanks.